# Mesh: LoopTools is not showing up

Tags: add-on

When I enable LoopTools in preferences, its as if I hadn't done it. the *Edit* tab does not show up at the side, my  <kbd>W</kbd> hotkey just cycles through selection tools. Yes I am in *Edit Mode*.

In the [video](https://youtu.be/0hM8GYaUnvs) I'll show how its definitely an issue with specifically looptools because other Mesh: plugins do in fact make the *Edit* tab appear.

I am on Macbook M1 Pro, MacOS Monterey.

Comment: You're trying to edit a curve, LoopTools is for meshes

Comment: Typically, looptools is accessed via the right-click menu in edit mode (with a mesh selected), however if you are attempting this on a curve, the option will not appear.

Comment: As the others pointed out, _LoopTools_ is for mesh objects. In the video when you enable the add-on in the _Preferences_ you even circle your mouse over the word **Mesh** where it says _Mesh: LoopTools_.